# Qual a melhor forma de se criar um relatorio de acessos?

Tags: php, mysql, relatório

Eu estou montando um site de receitas (PHP e Mysql) e gostaria de ter no backend um relatorio de acessos, onde eu consiga saber quais receitas cada usuário mais vê, para depois sugerir outras receitas baseadas nesses relatorios.

Eu pensei em montar uma tabela no Mysql do tipo:

```
id|id_receita|id_usuario|data       |visualizacoes
1 |   34     |   10     |2018-04-10 |    3
```

Aí a cada receita que ele ver, vai adicionando uma linha, e se ele ver a mesma receita no mesmo dia, soma as visualizações.

A minha dúvida é: isso pode deixar a tabela muito "pesada" quando tiver muitas receitas e muitos usuario? É a melhor forma de se montar um relatorio?

Obrigado!

Comment: O que você considera "pesada"? quantas linhas?

Comment: então isso que eu não sei, sou iniciante ainda em mysql, qts linha começa a fica mt pesado?

Comment: Quantas linhas você acha que seu banco poderá ter? dá um chute

Comment: espero que milhares...rs, mas qualquer numero que eu passar aqui é um chute, tem algum número de linha que possa já ser considerado muito?

Comment: Pois é, também não sei, mas tenho uma tabela com 15MB e as consultas são instantâneas.  Na tabela existe 7400 linhas com letras de musicas, se eu fizer um select com `a` retorna todos os registros instantaneamente

Comment: Mas para otimizar a consulta de uma lida nesse post https://www.profissionaisti.com.br/2011/09/indices-mysql-aumentando-a-velocidade-das-suas-consultas-em-ate-100x/

Answer (score 1):

Analisando o que você quer...

**Sugerir receitas para o usuário**

Há diversas formas de fazer isso:

**1.** Saber que usuário acessou qual receita e quantas vezes guardar no banco e selecionar receitas a partir desses dados

Você terá um campo com a chave primária da tabela (`id`), dois com a chaves estrangeiras do usuário (`id_usuario`) e da receita (`id_receita`), você possui algumas formas de saber essa quantidade:

**1.1.** Ter uma coluna quantidade e sempre somar mais um quando o usuário ver uma receita.

Isso é uma forma eficiente, mas não é mais completa, já que a única informação guardada vai ser quantas vezes o usuário acessou qual receita, mesmo que adicionado um campo data ela vai guardar apenas a última vez que determinado usuário acessou determinada receita

**1.2.** Guardar cada acesso numa linha diferente e para saber essa quantidade usar o `COUNT()` agrupando por usuario e receita

É um método mais custoso (mais dados para armazenar), mas isso permiti guardar mais dados que podem vir a ser úteis, por exemplo, você pode guardar o local em que a receita foi acessada e a partir daí sugerir receitas típicas daquele local

**2.** Você também pode criar um formulário em que o usuário especifica suas preferências

Nesse caso sugiro a criação de várias colunas: lactose, doce, salgado, nutritiva etc. e setar como `TRUE` as que tiverem determinada característica ou `FALSE` se não tiver

**3.** A forma menos custosa para o banco (menos dados para serem salvos, no caso, nenhum) é sugerir receitas a partir da receita atual, assim se o usuário estiver vendo uma receita X, vai ser mostrado pra ele receitas com características semelhantes a X

**IMPORTANTE:** Não se preocupe tanto com performance, não é necessário buscar todos os dados do banco imediatamente, busque inicialmente apenas a receita que o usuário esta visualizando e depois, através de AJAX, busque outras

Avalie o que você quer com a sua aplicação, se é realmente necessário ter tanto cuidado com um banco "pesado" e então escolha o que acredita ser o melhor

Comment: legal, eu acabei fazendo mais ou menos isso que você me passou, aí adicionei a regra se ele ficou mais de 30 minutos sem visitar essa receita e clicou de novo, aí adiciona uma nova linha